# Unit testing data layer's stored functions/procedures using OrmLite without an open connection

Tags: c#, postgresql, unit-testing, xunit, ormlite-servicestack

I am trying to unit test our DB layer's stored procedures/functions using OrmLite's `ScalarAsync()`, for example, with the PostgreSQL dialect. (I tried using SqlLite in-memory but it doesn't do stored procedures or functions.)

I found some hints in the unit-tests for OrmLite on GitHub as well as an [article](https://forums.servicestack.net/t/sqlitedialect-with-sqlproc-in-unit-tests/3245) which points to them.

Here's what I have:

```cs
    [Fact]
    public async Task TestMyMethod_CallsMyStoredProcedure()
    {
        // Arrange
        Mock<IDashboardDbConnectionFactory> mockConnFac = new();

        MockDialectProvider prov = new();
        prov.ExecFilter = new MockStoredProcExecFilter();
        
        OrmLiteConnectionFactory dbFactory =
            new(
                "User ID=asdf;Password=asdf;Host=localhost;Port=5432;Database=asdf;Pooling=true;Connection Lifetime=0;",
                prov, false);

        OrmLiteConfig.ExecFilter = new MockStoredProcExecFilter();
        mockConnFac.Setup(m => m.OpenAsync(It.IsAny<ISecurityContext>()))
            .Returns(async () =>
        {
            OrmLiteConnection asdf = new(dbFactory);
            OrmLiteConfig.ExecFilter = new MockStoredProcExecFilter();
            await asdf.OpenAsync();
            return asdf;
        });
        mockConnFac.Setup(m => m.Open(It.IsAny<ISecurityContext>()))
            .Returns(() =>
            {
                OrmLiteConnection asdf = new(dbFactory);
                OrmLiteConfig.ExecFilter = new MockStoredProcExecFilter();
                asdf.Open();
                return asdf;
            });
        
        // Act
        MyDataLayerCLass target = new(mockConnFac.Object, new NullLoggerFactory());
        bool test1 =
            await target.ExecMyStoredProcAsync(new Mock<ISecurityContext>().Object, Guid.NewGuid());

        // Assert
        Assert.True(test1);
    }

    private class MockDialectProvider : PostgreSqlDialectProvider
    {
        public MockDialectProvider()
        {
            base.ExecFilter = new MockStoredProcExecFilter();
        }
        public new IOrmLiteExecFilter ExecFilter { get; set; } = new MockStoredProcExecFilter();
    }
    
    private class MockStoredProcExecFilter : OrmLiteExecFilter
    {
        public override T Exec<T>(IDbConnection dbConn, Func<IDbCommand, T> filter)
        {
            try
            {
                T val = base.Exec(dbConn, filter);
                if (dbConn.GetLastSql() == "select central_data.my_stored_function(@UserId, @ParentId)")
                    return (T)(object)true;

                return val;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                if (dbConn.GetLastSql() == "select central_data.my_stored_function(@UserId, @ParentId)")
                    return (T)(object)true;
                throw;
            }
        }
        
        public override async Task<T> Exec<T>(IDbConnection dbConn, Func<IDbCommand, Task<T>> filter)
        {
            try
            {
                // This is where the breakpoint hits. Returns false b/c the ids
                // don't match actual records in the DB.
                T val = await base.Exec(dbConn, filter);
                if (dbConn.GetLastSql() == "select central_data.my_stored_function(@UserId, @ParentId)")
                    return (T)(object)true;

                return val;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                string sql = dbConn.GetLastSql();
                if (sql == "select central_data.my_stored_function(@UserId, @ParentId)")
                {
                    return (T)(object)true;
                }
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that it requires a valid connection to a valid database. So it's really an integration test when what I want is a unit test. Is there a way to run the dialect provider without an open connection?

Comment: So in the nutshell you want to execute stored procedure in database but without having one? Or what is the purpose of the test you are trying to write?

Comment: @GuruStron Basically I want to verify that my data layer eventually calls the correct stored procedure using dbConn.GetLastSql() and comparing the string. This test works, but it won't run without an open connection to an actual database, even if that DB doesn't have the schemas and functions/procedures in it.